# Simplest way to log in as Oracle user different from schema user and still see all tables,... of schema?

Tags: oracle, schema, users

What is the simplest way to log in as user X and see all tables,... of schema Y as if they belonged to X?

With an Oracle 11g database, I would like to log into the database using user `X` but all the data (tables, views, procedures, ...) would be stored in Schema `Y`.

All the code that accesses the tables is guaranteed to use unqualified names (`TBL_NAME`, not `Y.TBL_NAME`)

Searching for "schema alias" points to `CREATE SYNONYM`, but that would have to be done for each DML object, right? And since I only have unqualified calls, it seems a login trigger with `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ...;` should do the trick?

Any other options?

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA` will work, but you still need to do all of the grants.

Comment: @Phil - you mean X needs all rights on Schema Y ?

Comment: see if proxy authentication will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA
```

will work, but you still need to do all of the **grants**.

–  Phil Oct 29 at 23:33